# Change style of selected Text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

How can I change styles (such as Font, FontSize, Brush) of selected Text in `RichTextBox` ?

**Update :** Let's say I've a `RichTextBox` and a Toolbar. User comes and select text inside the RichTextBox box and change the font size from toolbar. I want to change style of selected text.

Comment: I've searched but I couldn't find any useful example DJ.

Comment: really, ok what are you wanting to do that you were not able to find on the web.. perhaps you should update your question and give an exact example of what you are wanting to do..

Comment: hopefully that will be enough to get you started..

Comment: Thank you DJ :D yes it's enough.

Comment: awesome Saber.. glad I could help out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WPF

```
if (this.TextEditor.Selection.IsEmpty)
    this.TextEditor.CurrentFontFamily = SelectedFont;
else
    this.TextEditor.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, SelectedFont);
```

or another WPF Example

```
 private void ChangeTextProperty(DependencyProperty dp, string value)
    {
        if (mainRTB == null) return;

        TextSelection ts = richTextBox.Selection;
        if (ts!=null)
            ts.ApplyPropertyValue(dp, value);
        richTextBox.Focus();
    }
```

here are some examples 
Windows 
Changing the Font & Font Color (not wpf)

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Tahoma", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

another example below (not wpf)

```
private void WriteTextToRichTextBox()
{
   // Clear all text from the RichTextBox;
   richTextBox1.Clear();
   // Set the font for the opening text to a larger Arial font;
   richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
   // Assign the introduction text to the RichTextBox control.
   richTextBox1.SelectedText = "The following is a list of bulleted items:" + "\n";
   // Set the Font for the first item to a smaller size Arial font.
   richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
   // Specify that the following items are to be added to a bulleted list.
   richTextBox1.SelectionBullet = true;
   // Set the color of the item text.
   richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
   // Assign the text to the bulleted item.
   richTextBox1.SelectedText = "Apples" + "\n";
   // Apply same font since font settings do not carry to next line.
   richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
   richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Orange;
   richTextBox1.SelectedText = "Oranges" + "\n";
   richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
   richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Purple;
   richTextBox1.SelectedText = "Grapes" + "\n";
   // End the bulleted list.
   richTextBox1.SelectionBullet = false;
   // Specify the font size and string for text displayed below bulleted list.
   richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
   richTextBox1.SelectedText = "Bulleted Text Complete!";
}
```

Comment: There is no property such a SelectionFont or SelectionColor, this is a WPF.

Comment: I will modify my answer hold one second

Answer (score 2):

For a WPF RichTextBox, you have to use the ApplyPropertyValue method to a TextRange.  You can get the selected TextRange using the Selected property of the RichTextBox instance.

```
var selection = myRichTextBox.Selection;
if (!selection.IsEmpty)
    selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, 10.0);
```

Comment: This is a WPF application not a WinForm.