# Inserting graphics into RichTextBox

Tags: c#, textbox, richtextbox

I have just started studying at an university and came up with an idea to manage my transcripts. It's basically a text editor with a small versioning system wrapped around it.

To avoid ending up with walls of black and white text I had the idea to add some presets for "graphics" (not sure what is the right word to use here). For example, if my professor writes down some kind of definition like this one:

> **Integral**
>
> Also called Riemann integral. the numerical measure of the area
>   bounded above by the graph of a given function, below by the x -axis, and on .........

I would like to wrap it into some kind of different background and styling, just like here on StackExchange on the quote above, with the press of a button. Another example is in one of my books:

[image: Not sure if copyright is required here, but anyways: Walter Saumweber, Dirk Louis: Visual C++ 2010]

Is it even possible to include such styling into a RichTextBox or should I look for alternatives / existing text editors?

Comment: This is __not__ easy. You would have to code the __raw rtf__. Doable, of course, but really hard. You can scim over the [rtf specifcations](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/269575) or [here](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm) to get a feeling. (A nice version comes from an [unexpected site](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch01.html)) Just about any alternative seems preferrable unless you are a compulsive coder ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, implementation Example is given to this URL [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874876/6002727)

and some code for knowledge purpose

```
 //Apply Some Font to selection
 richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
 // Apply same color of text
 richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Purple;
 //backgroud colour of Selection
 richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
```

One more thing is to clearify, if you want to make a text editor, you have to given combo box for colour, size etc, and change this on IndexChange Event.

Comment: Actually this will only color the text portions of a line, not the empty part :-(