# Change the writing fontstyle without changing the previously written text

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

This is my code for changing the font style to normal. But my problem is that it changes all of the text in the RichTextBox. What I want is that it will change the selected text and change the style of the text I will write.

```
        private void italicToggle_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        text.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Normal);
        text.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A textbox contains only "unformatted text."  That is, you can set the font or font style, etc for the whole textbox but not for a portion (selection).  To be able to change a portion of text you must use a RichTextBox ([RichTextBox Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox?view=net-5.0)).  And see this for an overview ([RichTextBox Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#editing-commands)).

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add that in. I am already using a richtextbox

Comment: in this case, see this: [Change style of selected Text in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874800/change-style-of-selected-text-in-richtextbox).  I think I think you should eliminate the second line `text.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;` as this sets the font style for the whole RichTextBox.